# JasperReports Server 5.5: Create Schedule not working

Tags: jasperserver

I just Installed *JasperReports Server 5.5.0* and tried to schedule a report, but clicking on the Submit button does not save the job

Using jasperreports-server-cp-5.5.0
On Ubuntu Linux 13.04

In Javascript Console I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'url' of undefined parameters.js:122
(anonymous function) parameters.js:122
Backbone.Events.trigger backbone-0.9.2-patched.js:166
_.extend.change backbone-0.9.2-patched.js:476
_.extend.set backbone-0.9.2-patched.js:317
Backbone.Model.extend.update job.js:447
(anonymous function) editor.js:383
Backbone.sync.call.success job.js:988
fire require-jquery.js:3039
self.fireWith require-jquery.js:3157
done require-jquery.js:9392
callback
```

Getting this Exception in the backend:

```
ERROR GenericExceptionMapper,http-bio-8080-exec-3:42 - Unexpected error occurs
com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException: null for uri:    http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/samples/AllAccounts/options
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1484)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.doFilter(StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:152)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:209)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:209)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.filter.BasicLoggingFilter.doFilter(BasicLoggingFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.JSCsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(JSCsrfGuardFilter.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.WebAppSecurityFilter.doFilter(WebAppSecurityFilter.java:76)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.encryption.EncryptionFilter.doFilter(EncryptionFilter.java:130)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.SessionDecoratorFilter.doFilter(SessionDecoratorFilter.java:43)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:67)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.P3PFilter.doFilter(P3PFilter.java:43)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 0):

i stumbled accross the same symptom. The weird thing is i managed to schedule a job yesterday.

After doing some experiments i think i found the cause and have at least a workaround.

It seems it is an error with the DatePicker and date formats. My date format is the German date format so it is dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm.

When selecting dates before the 13th of each month the scheduling works fine. As soon as i select a start date that is >= 13th it does not save the date.

If the schedule is saved and i reopen the schedule the input field shows me i.e. the following string:

2013-12-12 12:41

If i don't use the date picker again i can replace it in the input field with i.e.

2013-12-20 00:10

And everything is fine.

It is not an easy workaround but at least it works for me.

Best Regards

Constantin

Answer (score 0):

@user3095179: Your answer saved my day. After some heavy update troubles (importing Datasources&Reports manually as an sql-dump destroyed the posgresql db) with jasperserver 5.5 everything is working fine now.

I can verify the behaviour concerning the 13th, but I don't get it. Maybe the guys from jasper try to avoid friday the 13th.

There is room for improvement within the method you describe, to insert a date after the dreaded 13th:

You can directly circumvent the datepicker, and insert a date in the japanese format (according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx says), via copy&paste.

I am inserting this into the date timebox directly: 2014/03/28 03:00. But I just verified that your format 2013-12-20 00:10 works too, in that way.

So this whole answer sums up to: Always use Copy&Paste, so you don't have to open the schedule two times.

Nevertheless kudos to the the jasper developers.

EDIT:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/3255
So today I tried the process again, but this time with a report that expects parameters. The date trick was not working there. The solution is provided by a user named dnaboka who patched some javascript files, in this thread in #10, #11 and #13. In #13 Andy.c explains where to put the patched files. In a nutshell put the patched files to:

/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.5.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/scripts/scheduler/view/editor/parameters.js

and

/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.5.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/scripts/scheduler/collection/jobs.js

The reason some users there complain that this doesn't fix it, is

```
<speculatemode>
    It is related to the dreaded 13th date problem.
</speculatemode>
```

I believe to completeley circumenvent our workarounds with the copy&pastarino another stackoverflow user posted a permanent workaround here:
[Unable to Goto the Second Step of Scheduling on Jasper Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070817/unable-to-goto-the-second-step-of-scheduling-on-jasper-server). Again in a nutshell:

Within /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.5.0/WEB-INF/classes/esapi/security.properties, comment out the trigger.timezone line. Haven't verified this. Will do it in future.

Please don't upvote this message, just do it for the original problem solvers.